# Looking for an alternative to iterating thru layers of lists

Tags: c#, .net

This is a .Net C# program. Here is what I have, and it works, but is slow:

The outside collection has a list of records with a key, there are approximately 5500 values
The next collection has a list of accounts that exist for the key across all groups, there are approximately 5 to 10 values
The next collection has a list of groups that are required for the key, there are three groups (but they vary, so its not a constant list)

I need to figure out what adds need to happen. An add would be if one of the groups does not exist or if it is missing any of the accounts.

I start off with a list of existing keys/groups/accounts.

Currently I am using something like this:

```
foreach (rec in keysList)
    foreach (account in accountsList)
        foreach (group in groups)
            if (!existing.contains(keys/groups/accounts))
                add record
```

This is slow and seems like there should be an alternative to the multi-layer nesting.

Thanks,
Sammer

Comment: Hint: Use a hashtable for `O(1)` lookup. and you can pre-index your items in `O(n)` time and space.

Comment: What is the type of `existing`? How is `existing.Contains` determined?

Comment: It doesn't look like you are going to get more efficient than this, unless you cache data (as suggested with the hashtable - or as is available with other approaches).

Comment: Existing is a Hashset of records, I am using something like this 
if (Existing.Where(c => c.Key == key && c.Group == group && c.Account == account).Count() == 0) ... Add

Comment: HashSet<T>.Where() does not actually perform a hash lookup. You may as well replace it with a List<T>.

Comment: If you want to try something truly different, you can start with John Wu's flattening technique, sort both lists, and implement the merge match algorithm. That might perform better than the hash lookup if the two lists have a lot in common.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `HashSet<T>` correctly in order for it to perform as expected. Use `HashSet<T>.Contains(T key)`.

The problem you must solve is, your key type must implement (correctly) `IEquatable<Key>`, or you must pass in a custom instance of `IEqualityComparer<Key>` to the `HashSet` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten the list first:

```
var list = keyList.SelectMany
( 
    k => k.SelectMany
    (
        a => Select
        (
            g => new 
            {
                Group = g,
                Account = a,
                Key = k
            }
        )
    )
);
```

Once your structures are in flat lists, the rest is easy:

```
var difference = list.Except(otherList);
foreach (var d in difference)
    DoAdd(d.Key, d.Account, d.Group);
```

Note that anonymous types compare by value, not by reference (it compares all the individual properties, not the single object reference), so flattening the list into anonymous types also takes care of difficulty caused by difference references to the same data.

Comment: This won't improve efficiency though.

Comment: Well, it will improve developer efficiency. It might cause a bit more memory pressure. As for CPU, it's not entirely clear actually. Flattening the list will give you a nice clean cache pipeline and the number of comparisons I believe is fewer.